# Get the maximum value in the column periodically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have time series data with column that calculates 2-day sums. I want to get the last value in each 2 day period and write it in a column, by user id.

The data looks like (with desired output column 'new'):

```
df
timestamp           uid         cols        new
2020-10-10 00:00     1          10   
2020-10-10 00:00     2          5      
2020-10-10 00:10     1          20
2020-10-10 00:10     2          20
2020-10-10 00:20     1          40
 .... 
2020-10-11 23:50     1          3400        
2020-10-11 23:50     2          5250
2020-10-12 00:00     1           20        3400
2020-10-12 00:00     2           15        5250
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand.  Your title says "the maximum value" and in the question it says "the last value in each 2 day period".  Can you define what you mean by "last value"?

Comment: @Bill Yes, sorry for the confusion. The column 'cols' is a cumulative sum for each 2-day period, the max value will also be the last value.

Comment: Okay thanks.  In the question it says it is a "2-day rolling sum" not a cumulative sum.  Is it a rolling cumulative sum maybe?

Comment: I meant to say cumulative sum

Comment: Does the set of `uid` values change over time?  That could complicate things.

Comment: Oh I think I might have misunderstood.  It's not a rolling cumulative sum, it's a cumulative sum that resets at the end of each 2-day period.  Am I right?  Might help if you show the code that produced the values in `'col'`.